# sql query to sort by multiple conditions

Tags: sql, mysql, model, sequelize.js

I would like to know how to sort values in mysql query.

I have a table `tasks` and has column `cost` which can have null or number values

other column `status` have `2703, 2702, 2701`

Based on condition, the order by should be

-cost with value `null` and the status should be order `2701, 2702, 2703` always last

-cost with value `numbers` and status with only `2701, 2702` should be first

(i.e) cost with either null/number with status `2703` should be last.

Tried query

```
cost status
1    2703
null 2702
2    2701

Expected order should be

cost status
2    2701
null 2702
1    2703 // alwys status `2703` should be last after null if cost has either value/null



select * from tasks t1 where active = true 
ORDER BY t1.cost IS NULL, t1.cost asc, t1.statusId asc
```

Comment: Please update your question to explain why the SQL you’ve given doesn’t give the result you want. It would be helpful if you provided enough sample data to illustrate the possible use cases and show how you want that sample data sorted

Comment: @NickW  order by the cost values with status 2703 is not at last, sql query seems to be wrong

Comment: @NickW the query i tried works only for `cost with value null and the status should be order 2701, 2702, 2703 always last`

Comment: @NickW I need to know how to check this condition `cost with either null/number with status 2703 should be last.`

Comment: Hi - your comments really aren’t providing much clarity, to me, about what you are trying to achieve, hence my previous comment asking you to update your question with enough sample data to illustrate all the possible use cases (combinations of costs and status values) and the order in which you want them sorted, and why

Comment: @NickW, thanks for reply, have added scenario example to my question, if possible help

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from tasks t1 
where t1.active = true and t1.cost is not NULL and t1.statusID in (2701, 2702) 
union all 
select * 
from tasks t2 
where t2.active = true and t2.cost is NULL
```

Although re-reading your question it seems you just want NULL cost at the bottom.  For that all you need is
select * from tasks t1 where t1.active = true order by t1.cost, t1.statusID and null will go to the bottom

Comment: thanks for reply, i need to sort and not union

Comment: thanks for reply, have added an exxample, can help please in my question scenario

Comment: select * from tasks t1 where t1.active = true order by t1.statusID asc, t1.cost asc

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
select * from tasks t1 where active = true 
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN status = 2703 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END asc,
t1.cost IS NULL, t1.cost asc, t1.statusId asc
```